# Data send disallowed? [WinError 10057]

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, server

I know this is an error on the server part where the `s` variable is being used when the `conn` variable should be used but I've been sitting here for 2 hours and cant see the mistake. The error:`[WinError 10057] A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied` 
My code:

````
import socket
from _thread import *

server = '123.456.78.9'
port = 5555


s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

try:
    s.bind((server, port))
except socket.error as e:
    str(e)
    
s.listen()
print("Waiting for connections, server has been started")

def threaded_client(conn):
    reply = ""
    conn.sendall(str.encode("[Server, Server]Mis:200:Connected"))
    while True:
        try:
            data = conn.recv(2048)
            reply = data.decode("utf-8")
            
            if not data:
                print("Disconnected from", addr[0])
                break
            
            print("Received: ", reply)
            print("Sending: ", reply)  
            conn.sendall(str.encode(reply))
        except:
            break
    print("Connection to", addr[0], "has been lost!")
    conn.close()

while True:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    banlist = open('bannedip.bipf')
    if addr[0] in banlist.read():
        conn.sendall(str.encode("[Server, Server]Err:401:Banned"))
        conn.close()
        print("Banned ip", addr[0], ", was disconnected as their ip (", addr[0], ") is listed in the ban file")
    else:
        print("Connected to:", addr[0])
        start_new_thread(threaded_client, (conn,))```
````

Comment: You're correct. Are you sure this is the real code? NB I suggest you shouldn't send anything to a banned IP. Don't leak any information to them at all. Just close the connection.

Comment: may i ask what would this leak? Just curious

Comment: Also yes this is my code a direct copy and paste except for the ip

Comment: It would leak the information that (a) the IP:port exists and (b) that you recognize their IP:port as that of a bad actor. Both of these pieces of information could be of use to the attacker. Don't tell them nuthing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out! According to other people's `[WinError 10057]` problems its the server refusing to use a certain sock variable. Its been like 6 hrs and i decided to check my client code and it turns out that I first declared the `client` variable to be a normal socket in the `__init__` function. Then in my `connect` function takes this variable and modifies it to be a connected variable (so send and recv functions work in that function). Then my send function re-reads the original socket (non-connection) and uses that to send (which fails).So i did the very complicated equivalent version (in server words) of doing `conn, addr = s.accept()` then making `old_s = s` then s = conn then stupidly resetting conn = old_s. That's the best I can explain it i'm sorry if you didn't understand a word of it.